# it possible use a named variable for print a named group in closure in groovy?

Tags: java, regex, groovy, closures

something like this code

please help me

```
"56".replaceAll(/(?<name1>\d)(?<name2>\d)/){print name1}
```

Comment: What is name1 and name2 here? what is your expected output? please explain the question little bit more.

Comment: yes name1 and name2  are the name of the group of regex sentence ; I expected obtain the group name1  in this case "5" and print

Comment: this can do with regex  "56".replaceAll(/(?<name1>\d)(?<name2>\d)/, '${name1}') but  this not work for other purposes

Comment: What are you hoping to achieve?  What should the replaceAll do with the groups?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
"56".replaceAll(/(?<name1>\d)(?<name2>\d)/) {_, name1, name2 ->
      println name1
      println name2
}
```

Output:

```
5
6
```

See [this Groovy demo](https://ideone.com/MYYIfA)

The point here is that the match object returned by the `Matcher` contains 3 groups, i.e. it is equal to the number of capturing groups and the whole match itself as Group 0. Thus, you should provide all 3 to the closure arguments, then you may print whichever you like.

Comment: this works fine ;but its more difficult put the name two times that one tine ;  very thankyou for you help

Answer (score 1):

If I am understand correct your question, Get as a Map would help you forever. Like below shown code.

```
println getMap('12345').name1    

Map getMap (String input)
    {
        Map namemap = [:]

        input.eachWithIndex{val, id ->  id+=1 ; namemap["name$id"]=val}

        return namemap

    }
```